# Javascript functions inside ASP.NET User Control

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, user-controls, webforms

I created ASP.NET user control with javascript function :

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="BingTranslator.Web.WebUserControl1" %>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function example() {
        alert('<%=ExampleButton.ClientID%>');
        return false;
    }
</script>
<asp:Button ID="ExampleButton" runat="server" Text="Example"/>
```

I want to call "example" function when user move mouse to button, so I added attribute for button:

```
ExampleButton.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "example()");
```

It works well, but when I need two controls on same page I got a problems. ASP.NET generates code with two functions with same name, what is wrong:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function example() {
        alert('TestControl1_ExampleButton');
        return false;
    }
</script>
<input type="submit" name="TestControl1$ExampleButton" value="Example" id="TestControl1_ExampleButton" onmouseover="example()" />


<script type="text/javascript">
    function example() {
        alert('TestControl2_ExampleButton');
        return false;
    }
</script>
<input type="submit" name="TestControl2$ExampleButton" value="Example" id="TestControl2_ExampleButton" onmouseover="example()" />
```

And always onmouseover event on any button will call second function. I am able resolve this issue by adding java script code with client Id directly to attriburte onmouseover.

```
ExampleButton.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "[Here will be javascript code]");
```

But it is not very harmonious solution as for me. Please advise, how I can better resolve such issue.

P.S. There will be much more Javascript code, I added two string upper just for example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to register your scripts with [`ClientScriptManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.aspx) - this way they can be registered once, regardless of how often the control has been added to the page:

```
// Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

// Check to see if the startup script is already registered.
if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname1))
{
  String cstext1 = "alert('Hello World');";
  cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1, cstext1, true);
}
```

Comment: Yes, i tis a possible way, But I don't want to move javascript code into CS file due to it's huge size.

Comment: @Anton - Sounds like you need to refactor your CS file.

Answer (score 38):

I found a solution in another site which allows you to use external file

```
if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered("key"))

{

   string url = ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/file.js");

   Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("key", url);

}
```

Comment: Why isn't this the accepted solution? You're a life saviour :D

Answer (score 9):

You need to use **`this.id`**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    load_v<%= this.ID %>    
});

function load_v<%= this.ID %>(fromclick) {
    alert('anything');
}
```

So that even if you need two or more same controls in the same page they will have different ids.
Hope this Helps! cheers :)

Comment: But this will create many identical Javascript functions anyway, and that's what should be avoided. Also, I guess in the `ready` event you wanted to write `load_v<%= this.ID %>()`, right? And what's that `fromclick` for?