# ASP.NET Scope of user control for javascript functions

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, user-controls

So I have a user control that exists multiple times on a page. From the back end I can call userControl1.someFunction(); and specify which user control I want to call someFunction() for. But if I have a java-script function on the front-end of the user control I can't call it for individual user controls. All I have to do is call javaFunction(), but this doesn't specify which user control I want to call. So this is what I would like to be able to do, clientsideUserControl1.javaFunction(); Is this possible to do? What I have been doing is generating the function name dynamically IE: clientsideUserControl1_javaFunction(), but I feel like there has to be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that in this case it would be better to use a server control instead of a user control. Server controls seem to be a little more complicated to make but they do protect the scope of the javascript functions.

Here is a link that discusses the differences.
http://www.hotscripts.com/forums/asp-net/31174-difference-between-user-control-custom-server-controls.html

Comment: If you did want to use a user control, this seem like a good way to protect the scope -> http://programmerramblings.blogspot.com/2011/07/clientside-api-for-aspnet-user-controls.html

Answer (score 3):

usually you can have one function and have it perform it's work on the whole page or you can change it to take a parameter ( a reference to the usercontrol you're interested in )

That way you don't need to have multiple copies of the same javascript function.

So instead of

```
function CLIENTID_javascriptFunction{
}
```

You'd have on function at the global level :

```
function javascriptFunction(id){

}
```

and call it with the id of the dom object you're interested in. (use ClientID to get the DOM id of the control)

Comment: yes u r right but sometimes I had to go the (CLIENTID_javascriptFunction) instead of passing a large number of parameters to a global declared function

Answer (score -1):

one possible solution is this:

```
function <%= ClientID %>javaFunction()
{
  //code here
}
```

you will have a function declaration for each user control with the client ID of the control plus function name

Comment: This is basically what I have been doing. I'm hoping that the guys at Microsoft made a way to allow you to reference the user controls individuality, rather than calling it like this.

Comment: It will work, but its really ugly solution. Much better way to resolve that problem is mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416705/javascript-functions-inside-asp-net-user-control

Comment: @Jakub Szułakiewicz thanks for that. By the way if you really need a better solution, you should stop using web forms :) this answer is 4 years old